# Jquery Insert HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm using: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started to submit my form, Ajax styleee.

However the form submits correctly and the data is sent however the fields on the form continue to have data in them. How can I clear them on submit? Hiding the form and displaying thank you would also be acceptable?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#pollform').ajaxForm(function() { 
      $('#pollform').hide();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On success
    $('#pollform').reset();

Answer (score 0):

To reset the form on success use:

```
$('#pollform').ajaxForm(function() { 
  $('#pollform')[0].reset();
});
```

You need to use `[0]` so that you call .reset() on the dom element rather than the jQuery object.